# Optimize accesor function laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have accesor, this function return position order for records of my model:

```
public function getPositionAttribute()
{
    $n = $this->count();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        $s = $this->get(['id'])->toArray()[$i]['id'];
        if ($s == $this->id) {
            return $i + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

How I can optimize this code? I think, that he works very very slow, because I going through a lot of records. May be do this with `map` function? I tryied, but map return collection, but not a number. My code with map:

```
public function getPositionAttribute()
{
    $this->get(['id'])->map(function($item, $key) {
        if ($item->id == $this->id) {
            return $key + 1;
        }
    });
}
```

Map function return: `#[1,NULL]`, `#[NULL,2]` e.t.c.
How I can correctly do my accesor function?

Comment: Well you can do `$all = $this->all();` and then `foreach ($all as $record)` so you only query the database once. Still this looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use the count of records having an earlier assigned primary key? For example:

```
public function getPositionAttribute()
{
    return static::query()->where($this->getKeyName(), '<=', $this->getKey())->count() + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood what your code does correctly, I'd probably do it like this:

```
public function getPositionAttribute()
{
    $collection = $this->all()->pluck('id'); 

    $position = $collection->search($this->id); 

    return $position ? ++$position : 0;

    // 0 means the id could not be found
    // You could easily swap that out with null or false. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and let me know if it works...

```
public function getPositionAttribute()
{
    foreach($this->all()  as $key => $item) {
        if($this->id == item) return $key;
    };
}
```

remember the collection starts in 0 maybe you need to add 1 before return $key.